# Testing javascript code inside a function using mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, mocha.js

Supposing I have the following function inside an external javascript file sampleFunction.js:

```
function mathOperation(a,b){
    var sum = a + b;
    var diff = a - b;
    var product = a * b;
}
```

And I would want to perform unit tests on this function using mochaJS from another separate file, say test.js. In that file I want to test the mentioned function for different inputs, and test the results. For example, I want to check whether the sum is 30 and the difference is 10 if I pass (20,10) to the function.

So in my test file, the code would be like this:-

```
var expect = chai.expect;
describe('Testing the function mathOperation()',function(){
    //test cases for checking sum, difference and product in mathOperation()
    ...
    ...
});
```

How do I go about writing the test cases to check the values of the sum, difference etc?

The reason why I ask the question is to know how can we test much bigger functions written in javascript which do not return anything, and to know whether we can test and compare the values of the various variables inside the function.

Comment: How can you test the function if you don't return/expose anything from it? All you can do is test that `mathOperation` runs and doesn't throw an error.

Comment: that function seems isolated except that is taking parameters, that is not affecting outside world at all, I feel something missing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can we test much bigger functions written in javascript which do not return anything...

Unless that function updates / changes  *something* external then it can't be verified. The only thing you can test is that the function completed successfully.

> ...and compare the values of the various variables inside the function

You can't, and this is nothing to do with unit testing or Mocha in particular, this is just plain old JavaScript rules. Variables declared within a function are [scoped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx) to that function only, they can't be accessed externally.

Comment: If we test whether the function changes something external, then this would be sort of a functional testing right? How would a person perform unit tests on a function then?

Comment: @ashwinator yes but with the example given that's all you *can* do, effectively it would be a black box test. I think the problem is the design of your function, if you want to make it testable then you either need to return the result or expose the result *somehow*, otherwise how else can you verify it does it's job correctly? Surely there is no harm in returning the data (even if it's purely for the purpose of testing), you don't need to actually do anything with it in production.

Comment: True, it does makes sense.